# Mapping WPF events to Windows Forms events

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, events

I have a complex system that needs Winform events to work. However, I want to add WPF elements to it. So I need to map all WPF events to their winform counterparts. E.g. I have this method that transforms the MouseMove event in my derived ElementHost class.

```
    private void Child_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = e.GetPosition(null);
        System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs eventArgs = 
            new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs 
                (System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, 0, (int)point.X, (int)point.Y, 0);
        OnMouseMove(eventArgs);
    }
```

Note the difference between System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs (WPF) and System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs (Winforms).

The problem is that there are too many events that needed to be mapped this way. Is there any chance this can be achieved without writing my own mapping method for each event?

Comment: why do you need to map them all?

Comment: ElementHost implements OnMouseMove, what do you need that isn't implemented there?

Comment: Thanks for your criticism. I've added two more sentences for clarification.

Comment: @MBirchmeier: I want the MouseMove event to be fired from the WPF element (in my case UserControl1). The problem is the signatures of the WPF event and its winform counterpart are different. I want to map it to the winform signature.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to automatically do it since WPF and forms have different arguments and events, and fire them under different circumstances. You're trying to marry two disparate things and I suspect are on the road to nightmare.

What are you trying to achieve? I assume some kind of GUI abstraction? Your abstraction would probably be better moved further down the code, and let the GUIs operate how they want to.

EDIT: OK, I see from your edit you're implementing a facade over the WPF controls to allow them to operate in your forms environment. Can't see any other way than doing them manually. Do you really have to use WPF controls?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it must be WPF controls.

Comment: possibly there's some information in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I agree with Gaz there's no easy way to automatically do it.

The only thing I can recommend to make the transition easier is to create some common extension method to do everything, such as ToWinformsEvent.  The advantage of this is a lot of the controls will use the same child parameters, and by implmenting a standard extension method you can somewhat mindlessly convert a lot of the parameters (for example converting a point to a MouseEventArgs will likely be used across many of your functions)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the other posters, this can only be done manually. However it is possible to neatly wrap up the code so that you only implement it once.

In order to handle this in a recent project, I created a helper class called MouseManager. The MouseManager then had methods like this:

```
void Subscribe(IPublisWpfEvents publisher, ISinkMouseEvents target);
void Subscribe(IPublishWinformsEvents publisher, ISinkMouseEvents target)
void Unsubscribe(IPublisWpfEvents publisher);
void Unsubscribe(IPublishWinformsEvents publisher);
```

For WPF Usercontrols I would implement IPublishWpfEvents, and Winforms Usercontrols I would implement IPublisWinFormsEvents. The two interfaces would have the exact signatures for the built-in mouse events so no imlpementation was actually needed, just stick the interface on your usercontrol and that's it.

Finally, the MouseManager would wire-up events between publishers (of two different types) to subscriber (of single type). I had to create my own unified MouseArgs which had my own defined enumerations like MouseButton and MousePoint class.

A nice by-product of this was I now have interfaces to handle all my mouse events, meaning I can unit test publication and sinking of events using RhinoMocks or similar.

Hope this helps,